# Change text within iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to be able to find a phone number within an iframe and change it to something else. I know that it isn't possible to modify content in an iframe that's not within the same domain but are there any potential hackish-ways of doing so? Maybe placing an image over the phone number but outside of the iframe?

Comment: Sure. You kind of answered your own question there, pal. Just use `z-index` and `absolute position`ing.

Comment: Is it possible to get the position of an element in an iframe?

Comment: Ah, okay, so you want to know where the phone number element is located within the iframe then retrieve it dynamically? I would just go to the iframe's source page then figure that out, then apply it to your parent site's cover image. By the way, I'd also suggest changing your question to something where it states that you're wanting to find the position of the # dynamically.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to dynamically calculate the position. You're not allowed to access anything from an iframe for another domain. Also, the way the webpage in the iframe is rendered may be different depending on the browser of the person's computer.

Comment: You're trying to hack an iframe, presumably containing a site that you don't own, to change a phone number to another number, huh?

Comment: Yes the company I work for offers phone-tracking services and the customers are informed of this and want it. Nothing shady

Comment: I would suggest you try looking into building extensions for chrome and firefox if you want something to replace phone numbers on webpages. They're built in javascript as well, and can modify content on pages from any domain for the browser they're installed on.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the webpage, change the content, and output it within another blank iframe (not to mess with styles). You cal also parse the page, change it and then cache it.